# Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application.

Tags: search, central-administration

I'm creating Search Service Application using administrator account.

It shows error **Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application.**

[image]

Comment: And what were these "errors"?  Check the Event Log and the ULS for more information.

Comment: Found this log : Unprovisioning the local service instance for service application with name 'ca07988b-c1cb-4118-b267-b073eadefb2b' and type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminWebServiceApplication'.

Comment: Anything else of note around that?  Have you tried searching for that Guid throughout the log?  Unfortunately you haven't been given much to go on yet.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint in Virtual Machine and I also faced exactly the same problem. I could not resolve the issue. Can someone help?

Comment: @RahulChoudhary How you tried to configure your search service application?. Is it through ca or powershell? What's the user account that you used?. Which administrator account? Is that farm administrator? How about your DB account? Whether farm administrator has permission in DB?. Also check if the account having local machine administrator permission.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was server role as it was set to Application, once changed it to Application With Search, it worked.

Comment: To switch the Server Role in SharePoint (SSSE in my case) go to Central Admin, System Settings and then Convert Server Role Is This Farm. Mine was set to Front-End. I changed it to Application with Search and then was able to add a Search Service successfully!